# Open MS SQL TCP port (security)

Tags: mysql, sql-server, security, tcp

(I am not sure whether this question is for SO or other network.)

I have read several times that opening SQL Server TCP port for access from Internet is big security risk and all work must be done over web services or other ways. Is this true and why SQL Server is more vulnerable than IIS/Apache? The same question may be asked for MySQL as well.

Answer (score 2):

It's not that it's any more *"vulnerable"* per say, but you are opening up your server to other issues.

Like anything that is open on the net, you are opening your SQL server up to brute force attacks that **will** (depending your password strength this could be 10 minutes or millions of years) eventually break in.

One thing you can do to mitigate risk is look into a product like [RDPGaurd](https://rdpguard.com/) that effectively blacklists IP addresses that attempt to brute force your server.

All of the above said, the standard practice is to have applications interact via an API or webservice, but if you are simply trying to run something SQL Server Management Studio from your desktop and connect to your server on the internet, then you will have to open the SQL port and enable remote connections.

Comment: I want to use desktop application which connects to DB directly without web service. For MySQL the user access can be limited by remote IP and this has to help against brute force (root user disabled for external access). The user for specific application can be limited to access only its database with privilege only to execute stored procedures.

Comment: BTW, MySQL can be accessed over SSH. I hope this is enough secure. Maybe similar can be done for SQL Server?

Comment: Forgive me, I didn't realize that your question was about MySQL as your title references MSSQL...There are similar solutions for MySQL (assuming you are using linus as you mention ssh, such as fail2ban or keyonly logons) .. For a bare minimum though, only allowing certain remote IPs in is a good start.

Comment: The question was for MSSQL but also for MySQL. The web service solution is recommended for both databases and I suppose that security risk is similar. I know generally what could happen with direct DB server access but after so many recommendations to go over web service I want to verify whether I miss some detail.

Comment: An API or webservice would work well and should be used for an application, but if you are trying to access the remote DB over the internet using something like SSMS or one of the other SQL desktop programs, you will need to open those ports. RDP Gaurd or Fail2Ban and other measures can be put into place to ensure a reasonable level of security even with those ports open. Opening the port itself isn't the risk, the risk comes with you open the port but do not secure the server / database.